Deep Linking does not work when we Click on the URL
I am working on Xamarin Android, and I have made a custom shareable link for my application and verified the domain which I am going to use on that link. After deploying it on playStore and sharing the link, when I click on it, it opens the domain of that url rather than opening app when app is installed or taking to playStore when App is not installed.
I have used several different link but none of them works. Please find the details

app://abc.xyz.co.in?user=BXOKyvuohpfq8SChnAYvEg==&sightPathID=iPsDHHYxOZfr1x+iIHv/4Q==&app_package=com.xyz.android#Intent;scheme=https;end

intent://abc.xyz.co.in?user=Od7NdFvTUnoY4HjwybJx1w==&flightID=J6l70jOaTcnvGYbJAYNkBg==&app_package=com.xyz.android#Intent;scheme=https;end


3.https://abc.xyz.co.in?user=WO3CQXYZK1cjmz+icsMYcQ==&flightID=mZNid1APgem7d4LNVhunAg==&app_package=com.xyz.android#Intent;scheme=https;ends;end
I have changed the manifest file intent-filter like this, and change the scheme as per link.


Any Solutions will be greatly appriciated.
Thank you.
My goal is to setup the link so that opens app when app is installed or take me to playStore when App is not installed.
Currently running Android 14.
Edit:
Manifest file intent code

Can you please share your manifest file.
Other than that, I assume you forgot to host the https://abc.xyz.co.in/.well-known/assetlinks.json file.
More on that in the Android Official Docu: Verify Android App Links

What was the Android version that you were checking?
